# SQL constructs translated to OOP

Tags: sql, oop

As someone who comes from the world of Object Orientation, I find it rather difficult to wrap my head around SQL. Recently, however, I realized that the classical SQL construct

```
select X from Y where Z
```

is basically equivalent to the following OOP construct:

```
List<SomeType> results = db.query(new Matcher<SomeType> () {
  public boolean match(SomeType candidate) {
    return ...; // checks condition Z on candidate, returns true for match
  }
};
```

So my question is: What are the OOP equivalents for other SQL constructs, such as joins?

Comment: IMHO it seems like a rather futile exercise to try to translate SQL queries to OOP constructs, and I doubt it would help you to wrap your head around SQL. I think you'd make more progress by stopping to look for similarities and rather accept the differences. :)

Comment: Areed. Relational theorem, some good books on object orientation (which I somehow think are needed, too) would be better.

Comment: @deceze: It's not that I need to understand SQL as fast as possible. I was just asking out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the OOP equivalents for other SQL constructs, such as joins?

Imagine that we have a query like following:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA JOIN tableB ON tableA.b_id = tableB.id WHERE tableA.someFld < 50;
```

So you need to fetch every record from `tableA` that match condition from `WHERE` clause (`tableA.someFld < 50`). Then for every record from result set check whole `tableB` to find records that match `ON` clause.

```
// Pseudo-code
Query query = new Query();
query.where(new Matcher....);
query.join(new Matcher<SomeType>() {
  public boolean match(SomeType tableACandidate, SomeType tableBCandidate) {
    return tableACandidate.getBId() == tableBcaididate.getId();
  }
});

ResultSet result = query.execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think Microsoft's LINQ (Language Independent Query) has made an attempt at creating a language that can be used as an object-oriented version of SQL.  Hibernate's HQL would be another.  I'd recommend exploring both of those if SQL is giving you problems.  Maybe they can make it clearer to you.